# Transfer the System.out to another class and read from it

Tags: java

i am working on a selfmade console (API, with GUI) and wanted to transfer the output from a program A, using my console, to my console class B, then read a string from it (the output from program A).

All answers i found were about creating a new PrintStream around a ByteArrayOutputStream etc.

The reason why i want to do this, is because i want to keep the code as easy as possible for others (best solution: one method to call in the program,).

It would be great if something like this would be possible for the programmer using my API:

```
ConsoleAPI c = new ConsoleAPI();
c.setOutput(System.out);
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

I don't think, this is possible, but maybe it is. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you let yourself be inspired by the numerous logging frameworks which perform similar tasks.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your question. I have code that redirects `System.out` and `System.err` to my own class (used to display output from several classes that use `System.out.println()` in a Swing window). You need something like that?

Comment: @Axel: I have a GUI made with swing objects (a replica of the command-line from Windows) and i am using it as an API for other programs. So i would like to be able to "transfer" the System.out PrintStream as text into my selfmade console.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` is an object of type `PrintStream`.
You can pass it around between classes like any other `PrintStream` object.

So your `ConsoleAPI.setOutput` method needs to take a `PrintStream` as parameter.
Then you'll be able to do what you want.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

Comment: Yes, i know that and i tried it before - but then i wasn't able to read from that PrintStream. All methods i found were about creating a new PrintStream and not about using an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I once wrote to redirect System streams. Basically, calling `ConsoleHandler.redirectSystemStreams()` will give you an instance of `ConsoleHandler` that you can add listeners to. The listeners will be called when new output is available.

Hope that helps to get you started.

**ConsoleHandler**

```
package com.dua3.util.io;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class ConsoleHandler implements Closeable {

  public static final int SYSTEM_OUT = 1;
  public static final int SYSTEM_ERR = 2;
  public static final int COPY_TO_SYSTEM_OUT = 8;
  protected final ByteArrayOutputStream outBytes;
  protected final PrintStream out;
  protected final List<ConsoleListener> consoleListeners;

  public synchronized static ConsoleHandler redirectSystemStreams(int what) {
    final PrintStream oldSystemOut = System.out;
    final PrintStream oldSystemErr = System.err;

    final boolean copyToSystemOut = (what & COPY_TO_SYSTEM_OUT) != 0;
    final boolean redirectSystemOut = (what & SYSTEM_OUT) != 0;
    final boolean redirectSystemErr = (what & SYSTEM_ERR) != 0;

    ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler() {

      @Override
      public void close() throws IOException {
        // check state
        if (redirectSystemOut && System.out != this.out) {
          throw new IOException("System.out was redirected and can not be restored!");
        }

        if (redirectSystemErr && System.err != this.out) {
          throw new IOException("System.err was redirected and can not be restored!");
        }

        // restore System Streams
        if (redirectSystemOut) {
          System.setOut(oldSystemOut);
        }
        if (System.err == this.out) {
          System.setErr(oldSystemErr);
        }

        // call super implementation
        super.close();
      }

      @Override
      protected void contentChanged(String data) {
        super.contentChanged(data);
        if (copyToSystemOut) {
          oldSystemOut.append(data);
        }
      }
    };

    // redirect streams to console handler
    if (redirectSystemOut) {
      System.setOut(consoleHandler.getOut());
    }

    if (redirectSystemErr) {
      System.setErr(consoleHandler.getOut());
    }

    return consoleHandler;
  }

  public ConsoleHandler() {
    this.consoleListeners = new LinkedList<ConsoleListener>();
    this.outBytes = createByteStream();
    this.out = createOutputStream();
  }

  private ByteArrayOutputStream createByteStream() {
    return new ByteArrayOutputStream(256) {

      @Override
      public void flush() throws IOException {
        super.flush();
        flushBuffer();
      }
    };
  }

  private PrintStream createOutputStream() {
    return new PrintStream(outBytes, true);
  }

  void flushBuffer() {
    // append current content
    final String data = outBytes.toString();

    // debugging shows that system streams are flushed rather often even
    // when no new input was received, so suppress meaningless contentChanged
    // events
    if (!data.isEmpty()) {
      // reset the byte array
      outBytes.reset();

      // inform listeners
      contentChanged(data);
    }
  }

  protected void contentChanged(String data) {
    ConsoleEvent ce = new ConsoleEvent(data);
    for (ConsoleListener listener : consoleListeners) {
      listener.contentChanged(ce);
    }
  }

  public void addConsoleListener(ConsoleListener listener) {
    consoleListeners.add(listener);
  }

  public void removeConsoleListener(ConsoleListener listener) {
    consoleListeners.remove(listener);
  }

  public PrintStream getOut() {
    return out;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws IOException {
  }
}
```

**ConsoleListener**

```
package com.dua3.util.io;

import com.dua3.util.io.ConsoleEvent;

public interface ConsoleListener {

  void contentChanged(ConsoleEvent ce);

}
```

**ConsoleEvent**

```
package com.dua3.util.io;

public class ConsoleEvent {

  private final String data;

  public ConsoleEvent(String data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public String getData() {
    return data;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'l have a look into it after school.